# Embedding XML representation of a DataSet into larger custom format file. Is it good practice?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

Is it a good practice to use XML data representing DataSet object as a part of a bigger custom file? Are there other ways to represent contents of DataSet inside such file?

My application uses custom file format to store information about objects and a large chunk of binary data. It uses DataSet class to describe behavior of objects in tabular manner. XML representation of DataSet is saved as a tag-separated block into a header of that file. The header is followed by a bulk binary data block.

Principal example of such file below:

```
   !magicword
   [fileinfo]
   some information about the file here
   [/fileinfo]
   [xmlstream]
   DataSet XML representation here
   [/xmlstream]
   [bin]
   binary data starts here and lasts until end of file
```

1. Something tells me XML data created by DataSet.WriteXml() is supposed to be used in standalone files only. Is it ok to embed it into something else?
2. When XML data becomes large (say several tens of MBs) it's getting less handy, are there other more compact ways to represent DataSet contents?

P.S. DataSet always has fixed schema

Comment: *are there other more compact ways to represent DataSet contents?* - do the data sets have a fixed schema?

Comment: @dbc, thanks for your question. Datasets have same fixed schema. I added that remark in the question post

Comment: It is not normally done but I do not see anything wrong.  the read/write Dataset XML method writes to a file or stream so you would need to use a MemoryStream if you do not want to create a temporary file.

Comment: @jdweng yes, I use MemoryStream to handle portion of data that belongs to XML. The question is more about the approach itself whether it's good to make such 'hybrid' files

Comment: While I think this could work, a better solution might be to use the [`Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.package?view=netframework-4.7.2) object from the [`System.IO.Packaging` Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging?view=netframework-4.7.2).  It allows you to combined several different components into a zip file and also specify relationships between then so that content can be located.  This is the underlying file structure used by the open office XML formats.

Comment: @dbc, thanks for fruitful suggestion! Zipping all the contents would be an option although large binary blocks I'd like to keep unzipped as they can be several GBs in size (raw image data), zipping would slow down access time.

Comment: You can create package parts that are uncompressed, see [`CreatePart(Uri, String, CompressionOption)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.package.createpart?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Packaging_Package_CreatePart_System_Uri_System_String_System_IO_Packaging_CompressionOption_).  The main point of my is that the `Package` provides a convenient way to organize multiple chunks of data in one form or another into a single entity.  My experience is that the compression works very well with XML data and can reasonably be disabled for binary.